# session based authentication in next.js with express-sessions

Tags: express, authentication, session, next.js, express-session

hello i am trying to implement session based authentication for my next.js custom server express app .when i login session is set and it work as the way i expected but after few seconds or few request it don't. when i console.log(req.session) session is present but req.session.isLoggedin is disappeared.I want to implement session base authentication with database.

////server.js

```
/SOME NEXT.JS CUSTOM SERVER CODE/

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const session = require('express-session');
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  const Mongodbstore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);

  const mongodburl = 'MONGODB_URL';
  const server = express();
  const store = new Mongodbstore({
    uri: mongodburl,
    collection: 'sessions',
  });

  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  server.use(
    session({
      secret: 'VggyuvyhfSvcj',
      name: 'sessionID',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 100000,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: false,
      },
      store: store,
    })
  );
  server.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const { user, password } = req.body;
    if (user === 'hello') {
      req.session.isLoggedin = true;
      return res.redirect('/home');
    }
    return res.redirect('/');
  });

  server.post('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.destroy((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect('/home');
      }
      res.clearCookie('sessionID');
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  });

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });
/SOME NEXT.JS CUSTOM SERVER CODE/
```

//// page/home.js

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Logo />
      <Nav />
      <div className="body">
       HOME
      </div>
      <Foot />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(contex) {
  const { req, res } = contex;
  console.log(req.session);
  if (!req.session.isLoggedin) {
    return { redirect: { destination: '/', permanent: false } };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      user: 'USER1',
    },
  };
}
```

console.log

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-05-15T05:03:12.921Z,
    originalMaxAge: 100000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    domain: null,
    sameSite: 'strict'
  },
  isLoggedin: true
}
```

after few seconds or request

```
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2021-05-15T05:03:27.188Z,
    originalMaxAge: 100000,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    secure: false
  }
}
```

i don't know why **isLoggedin** is disappeared after few request. but session is present in database and cookie in browser.

Comment: yes @juliomalves .i edit the question

Comment: did you find solution?